# Regex: Replace double double quotes (solved), but only in lines that contain a special string (subcondition unsolved)

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

**1. Summary of the problem**

I have a csv file where I want to replace normal quotes in text with typographic ones.

It was hard (because HTML is also included), but I have meanwhile created a good regex expression that does just the right thing: in three "capturing groups" I find the left and right quotation marks and the text inside. Replacing then is a piece of cake.

**2. Regex engine**

I can use the regex engine of Notepad++ (boost) or PCRE2 comaptible, for developping and testing purposes I have used https://regex101.com.

**3. What I'm having a hard time with and just can't get right, where I need your help is here**:

I want to add a sub condition, in order to find the text in quotes only in certain lines, want to identify these lines by the language, e.g. ENGLISH or FRENCH (see also example in the screenshot).

[Screenshot of a sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvYvn.png)

The string indicating the language is always in the same line before the text to be found, BUT only the text in quotes (main condition) should be marked after matching the sub condition, so that I will be able to replace them.

It is about a few thousand records in the csv file, in the worst case I could also replace it manually. But I'm pretty sure that this should also work via regex.

**4. What I have tried**

Different approaches with look arounds and non-capturing groups didn't lead me to the desired result - possibly because I didn't really understand how they work.

An example can be found here: https://regex101.com/r/ketwwm/1

The example can be found here, it only contains the regex expression to match and mark the (three) groups WITHOUT the searched subcondition:

```
("")([^<>]*?)("")(?=(?:[^>]*?(?:<|$)))
```

Hopefully anyone in the community could help? (Hopefully I have not missed anything, it's my first post here )

**5. Update 03/18/2022: Almost resolved with two slightly different approaches (thank you all!) What is still unsolved ..**

1. Solution of @Thefourthbird (see answer 1)
   ^(?!.*?"ENGLISH")[^"]*".*(*SKIP)(*F)|("")([^<>]*?)("")(?=(?:[^>]*?(?:<|$)))

Nearly perfect, just missing matches in an HTML section. HTML sections in the csv file are always enclosed by double quotes and may have line feeds (LF). https://regex101.com/r/x5shnx/1

2. Solution of @Wiktor Stribiżew (see in comments below)
   ^.*?"ENGLISH".*?\K("")([^<>]*?)("")(?=(?:[^>]*?(?:<|$)))

The same with matches in HTML sections, see above. Plus: Doesn't match text in double double quotes if more than one such entry occurs within a text. https://regex101.com/r/I4NTdb/1

[Screenshot (only to illustrate)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LPc2.png)

Comment: Do you want `^"FRENCH".*?\K("")([^<>]*?)("")(?=(?:[^>]*?(?:<|$)))`? See https://regex101.com/r/ekACCH/1

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is funny: on my sample text it works well. But when I apply it on the original csv it 101 shows "no match".. I tried it back and forth ... no way

Comment: "when I apply it on the original csv" - what exactly are you using?

Comment: I have to add that: In the original, the string for the language is preceded by another column, it contains a text string in quotes and an immediately following comma (or alternatively just a comma): `"xyz",` or `,`

Comment: So, a line does not start with `"FRENCH"`? Then use `^.*?"FRENCH".*?\K("")([^<>]*?)("")(?=(?:[^>]*?(?:<|$)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match multiple occasions, you can use SKIP matching all lines that do not start with FRENCH:

```
^"(?!FRENCH")[^"]*".*(*SKIP)(*F)|("")([^<>]*?)("")(?=(?:[^>]*?(?:<|$)))
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `"` Match literally
- `(?!FRENCH")` Negative lookhead, assert not FRENCH" directly to the right
- `[^"]*"` Match any char except `"` and match `"`
- `.*(*SKIP)(*F)` Match the rest of the line and skip it
- `|` Or
- `("")([^<>]*?)("")(?=(?:[^>]*?(?:<|$)))` Your current pattern

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6QCNuK/1)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply, it is so helpful. Alas, when I apply it on the original csv it shows "66 matches" - whatever I enter instead of "FRENCH". That surprised me because on the sample I gave you it worked like a charm (with ENGLISH, GERMAN etc.). Maybe I have to add, that in the original there is another column before the language string, it may contain a textstring in double quotes and a comma ("xyz",) or only a comma (,)

Comment: @LBX If "FRENCH" can be any column, you can still assert that from the start of the string like `^(?!.*?"FRENCH")[^"]*".*(*SKIP)(*F)|("")([^<>]*?)("")(?=(?:[^>]*?(?:<|$)))` https://regex101.com/r/YbvncT/1

Comment: You guys are just amazing Thefourthbird an @WiktorStribiżew. Thank you both so much. I just found little things now.

Comment: Without the sub condition I had 131 search results in the original csv file. With yours, Thefourthbird, I came up with a total of 112, and with WiktorStribiżew, 99. In the meantime, I have examined everything and have at least been able to figure out which pattern is not being matched (yet).  For both of you, entries are not found that are in an HTML section. HTML sections in the csv file are always marked like this: Enclosed by double quotes and line breaks within by LF (not CRLF). With Wiktor, entries with double double quotes are not found if more than one such entry occurs within a text.

Comment: For both cases I have included entries in the example. Thefourthbird: https://regex101.com/r/x5shnx/1 , @WiktorStribiżew: https://regex101.com/r/I4NTdb/1

Comment: I added another update in the question above. Hopefully I do not annoy you with it, I am in any case already very grateful to you, how far I have now already come

Comment: It seems really to be an issue that there is an LF within the html. Is regex able to distinguish between LF and CRLF? Because by CRLF a row ist terminated and LF is only a break in HTML. But visually it seems to be the same, at least in regex 101.

Comment: @LBX The pattern uses negated character classes `[^<>]*` that match any character except `<` and `>`. There is no specific match for LF or CRLF, it will match both.